# How to store mulitple data from a textarea in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, textarea

I have a textarea and a submit button and on click of the button I want that all the data seperated by a new line inserted into an array.

Here is the form file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="export.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="num1" placeholder="Enter Numbers You Want To See records Of....">
    
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And Here is the PHP file

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$newnum = '';
            $a = array($_POST['num1']);
            foreach($a as $i=>$checknum) {
                $newnum = "'".$checknum."'".',';
            }
            $newnum = rtrim($newnum,',');

            echo "$newnum";
                 ?>
```

This is what I am expecting:
Input -

```
1111
222
333
444
55
```

Output - '1111','222','333','444','55'

Comment: Should the output be an array instead of a comma separated string?

Comment: no it should be a comma separated value because it will be used further in mysqli query as select * from table where number in ($a)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "1111\n222\n333\n444\n55";

echo $a . PHP_EOL;
/*
1111
222
333
444
55
*/

// explode("\n", $a) ->
//      Explodes input by new line into following array [1111, 222, 333, 444, 55]
// fn($line) => "'$line'" ->
//      anonymous function that takes one input and wraps it between ''
//      Replace with function($line) {return "'$line'";} if using PHP < 7.4
// array_map ->
//      takes a callback function and an array and returns a new array by applying a callback to each item
// implode(',', ...) ->
//      join all elements in new array with a separator ','

$newnum = implode(',', array_map(fn($line) => "'$line'", explode("\n", $a)));

echo $newnum;
/*
'1111','222','333','444','55'
*/
```

Actually you could just implode them with `"','"` and add `'` to both ends.

```
$newnum = "'" . implode("','", explode("\n", $a)) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$newnum = '';
$a = explode("\n", $_POST['num1']);
foreach($a as $i=>$checknum) {
   $newnum. = "'".$checknum."'".',';
}
$newnum = rtrim($newnum,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$res = array_filter(array_map(function($value){
    return trim($value);
}, explode("\n", $a)));
```

Even if the person add lot of spaces ou add lot of new lines, the code will work.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

assume input from textarea is:

```
7
10
55


$textbox_string = '7'.PHP_EOL.'10'.PHP_EOL.'55';

$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $textbox_string);
$in_nums_query_str = implode(',', $arr);
$in_nums_query_str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $in_nums_query_str);
$in_nums_query_str = str_replace(",", "','", $in_nums_query_str);
$in_nums_query_str = "'" . $in_nums_query_str . "'";

echo $in_nums_query_str;
```

will echo

```
'7','10','55'
```